# For-loop Syntax Error in Sqlite3.c

Tags: c, sqlite, syntax-error, cppcheck

cppcheck has determined that the following statement produces a syntax error in sqlite3.c:

`for(i=0; i<db->nDb; i++){`

Full function:

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE void sqlite3BtreeLeaveAll(sqlite3 *db){
  int i;
  Btree *p;
  assert( sqlite3_mutex_held(db->mutex) );
  for(i=0; i<db->nDb; i++){
    p = db->aDb[i].pBt;
    if( p && p->sharable ){
      assert( p->wantToLock>0 );
      p->wantToLock--;
      if( p->wantToLock==0 ){
        unlockBtreeMutex(p);
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

I do not see how it is a syntax error. Please explain. Is this a false positive?

Comment: Looks fine to me, and obviously it does compile - I have to say I've always found cppcheck almost completely worthless.

Comment: Could it possibly be getting confused by the `assert` macro? Just a wild guess.

Comment: You may find this interesting reading http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q17

Comment: @mu is too short. Doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a false positive, however I can't reproduce it using Cppcheck 1.48 and C source code for SQLite 3.7.6.3.

If you're using different source or a different version, please [log it as a bug](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/newticket).

Answer (score 1):

CppCheck may be parsing the comparison expression incorrectly.
Try adding some spaces or parenthesis to help out,
Original:

```
i<db->nDb
```

Modified:

```
i < db->nDb
```

This is just my guess.

Comment: Good guess, but incorrect. Cppcheck parses that line as `for ( i@2 = 0 ; i@2 < db@1 . nDb@5 ; i@2 ++ ) {`.